# RHEL6 not registering correctly when using PXE boot via Cobbler

Tags: rhel, pxe, cobbler

When I create a RHEL6 server using the DVD media, it works fine. However, we want to do PXE installs.

We import the RHEL6 DVD to cobbler by doing the following:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop,ro rhel6-dvd.iso /media
$ sudo cobbler import --path=/media/ --name=rhel-6 --arch=x86_64
```

The install goes through fine. However, it seems that the registration isn't completed correctly. Here is the output:

```
The system has been registered with id: (snipped ID) 
Installed Product Current Status:
```

With a regular install, I'd get a list of products. When I do `yum repolist`, I don't get any of the RHN repos:

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
repo id          repo name                                                status
epel             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64           8,312
repolist: 8,312
```

Any idea why it is not registering correctly via `cobbler` but working fine when using DVDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was copying the DVD media to the local volume (`cp -rp /media <cobbler path for media>`) and pointing `cobbler` to that.

I got to this solution after comparing both trees---that of the DVD and that of the results of a `cobbler import`. Apparently, `cobbler import` doesn't copy some files for whatever reason. These missing files seem to include the mechanism that RHEL uses to identify the product.